# php mail проблемы с отправлением второго письма

Tags: phpmailer

В своём магазине, после каждого заказа я должен отправлять два письма, первое из которых админу, а второе - юзеру, уведомление о том, что его заказ успешно отправлен. Если с первым никаких проблем нет, то при отправке второго я вижу следующую страницу (после нажатия кнопки "отправить")
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код следующий:

```
<?php
class ControllerInformationCustomOrder extends Controller {
    private $error = array();

    public function index() {

        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {

            $mail = new Mail();
            $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
            $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
            $mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
            $mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
            $mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
            $mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
            $mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');

            $mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
            $mail->setFrom($this->request->post['email']);
            $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            $mail->setSubject("Новый индивидуальный заказ от " . $this->request->post['name']);

            $messageHtml = "
                <table>

                <tr>
                <th><h1>Заказ от</h1></th> <th><h1>" . $this->request->post['name'] . "</h1></th></tr>
                <tr>
                <th><label>Номер телефона:</th><th> " . $this->request->post['phone'] . "</label></th></tr>
                <tr>
                <th><label>Email заказчика:</th><th> " . $this->request->post['email'] . "</label></th></tr>
                <tr>
                <th><label>Товар: </th><th>" . $this->request->post['product_name'] . "</label></th></tr>
                <th><label>Текст заказа</label></th><td colspan=\'1\'>
                <span>" . $this->request->post['order_description'] . "</span></td></tr>
                </table>
            ";

            $mail->setHtml($messageHtml);
            $mail->send();
```

ВТОРАЯ ЧАСТЬ, ВТОРОЕ ПИСЬМО (КОТОРОЕ ПОРОЖДАЕТ ПРОБЛЕМУ НА СКРИНЕ):

```
$mail2 = new Mail();
    $mail2->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
    $mail2->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
    $mail2->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
    $mail2->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
    $mail2->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $mail2->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
    $mail2->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');
    $mail2->setTo($this->request->post['email']);
    $mail2->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
    $mail2->setSender(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    $mail2->setSubject($this->request->post['name'] . " ваш заказ оформлен!");
    $messageHtml2 = "Что-то отправляем клиенту";
    $mail2->setHtml($messageHtml2);
    $mail2->send();


    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('information/custom_order/success'));
}
if (isset($this->request->post['product_id'])) {
    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('product/product&product_id=' . $this->request->post['product_id']));
}
```

}

Comment: а при отправке через mail-функцию то же самое выдает или нормального проходит?

Comment: через функцию mail php всё норм проходит

Comment: попробуйте еще проверить отправку писем через mail в консоли. вполне возможно, что провайдер выставил ограничения на протокол smtp на самом хостинге. как понимаю, проблема только с gmail? письма могут не отправляться из-за политики безопасности на хостинге.

Comment: в самом скрине пишет, что письма на gmail идут через yandex pdd. вполне возможно, что ошибка на этом уровне из-за неправильной настройки пересылки.

Comment: этот же код работает в другом месте сайта. и оба письма отправляются должным образом на интересующей меня странице где лежит этот код. единственная моя проблема - это вывод логов на скрине. я не понимаю в чём проблема.

Comment: через яндекс письма идут, потому что они отправляются через почту яндекс, которая в переменной 'config_email', так что я думаю проблема точно не в этом

Comment: хм, странно... а еще есть какие зависимости? сам код в целом нормальный, не думаю что проблема зарыта в нем. скорее всего что-то связанное с настройками отправки.